# Unsubscribe fail in Angular

Tags: angular

I have code where i a am fetching some data with the HttpClient.I am subsribed to the method that returns that data.What if the taking of that data is too long for example eight seconds and when the home component is initialised ,then the process of fetching data starts through the ngOnInit lifecycle method.But what if the user after the starting of this process,which takes 8 seconds,navigates to other page after 2 seconds ? I dont want the subscription to be continued because it will be not needed anymore because that data i want to be showed on the compo component not on the other page.
I've tried this where with setTimeOut i am simulating that 8 seconds taking from back end,but it does not work.When i go to other page then i get the data in the console so the fetch is done until the end

```
 constructor(public mainService: MainService) { }

subscription: Subscription;
ngOnInit() {
      this.subscription = this.mainService.getAllPosts().subscribe(x => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(x);
      }, 8000);
    });
}

 ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    console.log("destroyed");
  }


//service method
  getAllPosts() : Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.url);
  }
```

Comment: the angular http requests closes automaticaly after reseving response, no need to unsubscribe

Comment: Check this out: https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-how-to-cancel-http-calls-on-router-change/

Comment: This code does not delay the observable event by 8 seconds, the subscribe effect will happen as soon as the http request is complete, it is just that the effect you are doing will take 8 seconds to show.

Comment: Just use the `takeWhile` operator. It do the job flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you do with the data but you can use async pipe to handle the observable one feature of async pipe is going to unsubscribe automatically on component destroy.

*component*

```js
data$:Observable<any>;
ngOnInit() {
      this.data$ = this.mainService.getAllPosts()
}
```

*template*

```html
{{data$ | async | json }} jsut an example
```

> async pipe will subscribe and get the data and unsbscribe when the
>   component destroy

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is fine, this is the code you want to test it with:

```js
constructor(public mainService: MainService) {}

subscription: Subscription;
ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.mainService.getAllPosts().subscribe(x => {
        console.log(x);
    });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    console.log("destroyed");
}


//service method
getAllPosts(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.url).pipe(delay(8000));
}
```